# Post XML in Java and Get the response code

Tags: java, xml, post

I need to send XML data to a URL. The XML data is contained in a stringbuffer.
I need to post it and get the response code.

Can anyone tell me how to do it?

I have a piece of code, but eclipse says its deprecated

```
PostMethod postMethod = new PostMethod(URL);
InputStream stream = new StringBufferInputStream(command);
                postMethod.setRequestBody(stream);
```

Comment: Please, be more specific on what you are using. Most probably you are using Apache HTTP Client, but it may not be clear to everyone. Otherwise, javadoc is worth reading before posting anything.

Comment: Sorry abt it. I am using the following:import org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Javadoc](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/apidocs/org/apache/commons/httpclient/methods/EntityEnclosingMethod.html#setRequestBody%28java.io.InputStream%29) says to use [setRequestEntity(RequestEntity)](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/apidocs/org/apache/commons/httpclient/methods/EntityEnclosingMethod.html#setRequestEntity%28org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.RequestEntity%29) instead.